# mongo + spring data + aggragate sum

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am looking for a solution without spring data. My project  requirement is to do without spring data.

To calculate the sum using aggregate function by mongo command, able to get output. But same by using spring data getting exception.
Sample mongo query :

```
db.getCollection('events_collection').aggregate(
{ "$match" : { "store_no" : 3201 , "event_id" : 882800} },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$load_dt", "event_id": { "$first" : "$event_id" }, "start_dt" : { "$first" : "$start_dt" }, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : 1 } },
{ "$project" : { "load_dt" : "$_id", "ksn_cnt" : "$count", "event_id" : 1, "start_dt" : 1, "_id" : 0 } }
)
```

Same thing done in java as,

```
String json = "[ { \"$match\": { \"store_no\": 3201, \"event_id\": 882800 } }, { \"$group\": { \"_id\": \"$load_dt\", \"event_id\": { \"$first\": \"$event_id\" }, \"start_dt\": { \"$first\": \"$start_dt\" }, \"count\": { \"$sum\": 1 } } }, { \"$sort\": { \"_id\": 1 } }, { \"$project\": { \"load_dt\": \"$_id\", \"ksn_cnt\": \"$count\", \"event_id\": 1, \"start_dt\": 1, \"_id\": 0 } } ]";

BasicDBList pipeline = (BasicDBList) JSON.parse(json);

System.out.println(pipeline);

AggregationOutput output = col.aggregate(pipeline);
```

exception is :

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "somrandomserver/10.10.10.10:27001" , "errmsg" : "exception: pipeline element 0 is not an object" , "code" : 15942 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

Could someone please suggest how to use aggregate function with spring?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (untested) **[Spring Data MongoDB aggregation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation)** equivalent

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = repository.getMongoTemplate();
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("store_no").is(3201).and("event_id").is(882800)),
    group("load_dt")
        .first("event_id").as("event_id")
        .first("start_dt").as("start_dt")
        .count().as("ksn_cnt"),
    sort(ASC, previousOperation()),
    project("ksn_cnt", "event_id", "start_dt")
        .and("load_dt").previousOperation()     
        .and(previousOperation()).exclude()
);

AggregationResults<OutputType> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,
                                            "events_collection", OutputType.class);
List<OutputType> mappedResult = result.getMappedResults();
```

As a first step, filter the input collection by using a match operation which accepts a Criteria query as an argument.

In the second step, group the intermediate filtered documents by the `"load_dt"` field and calculate the document count and store the result in the new field `"ksn_cnt"`.

Sort the intermediate result by the id-reference of the previous group operation as given by the `previousOperation()` method.

Finally in the fourth step, select the `"ksn_cnt"`, `"event_id"`, and `"start_dt"` fields from the previous group operation. Note that `"load_dt"` again implicitly references an group-id field. Since you do not want an implicit generated id to appear, exclude the id from the previous operation via `and(previousOperation()).exclude()`.

Note that if you provide an input class as the first parameter to the **`newAggregation`** method the `MongoTemplate` will derive the name of the input collection from this class. Otherwise if you don’t not specify an input class you must provide the name of the input collection explicitly. If an input-class and an input-collection is provided the latter takes precedence.

Comment: I am looking for a solution without spring data. My project is not allowing me to use spring data.